# Gulp and Three js not allowing import or require

Tags: javascript, three.js, gulp

I want to use Gulp in my future projects, but what it is more important to me is to add **Three.js** modular functionality, to the project, with normal plugins example uglify i dont have any problems, but when i run my gulp file in my js code theres always a **error THREE is not defined**, or if i type

> **var THREE = require('three');**

it says require is not defined, the same if i add a import,

> **import * as THREE from "three";**

*import is not defined*

hope i had expressed my problem correctly.

This is my Gulpfile.-

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var THREE = require('three');


gulp.task('build', () =>
  gulp.src('app.js')
    .pipe(bro({
      transform: [
        babelify.configure({ presets: ['es2015'] }),
        [ 'uglifyify', { global: true } ]
      ]
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')
        )))
    gulp.watch('*.js', ['build'])


// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'scripts', 'watch', 'build']);
```

---

**EDIT**: Think i got it, the documentation of a site was not complete, and i didnt knew i had to install Browserify also with gulp-bro, that seems to be the same, anyway that fixed the require problem. (bringing other new ones) Thank you for everything, and hope this helps somebody.

**EDIT2**: Now i have found out that Rollup.js is a better solution, with Babel, theres Rollup npm s for that, good luck.
Thank you.

Comment: can you add a bit about *how* you are using gulp? Configfile for instance would help.

Comment: yes i have tried with npm and Webpack, still same error, now i have tried with npm and Gulp-Bro, same results, it is like Browserfy, also node js. Tried to add the npm install three and nothing happens. Thank you

Comment: I assume you have seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248952/es6-import-of-three-js

Comment: @gaitat yes i have seen that still error Unexpected error import

Comment: I don't see any reason to include `three` in your gulp file. You should be importing it into your javascript `app.js` and using it's classes.