# Cannot integrate three.js with create react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, three.js, babeljs, create-react-app

I have been trying to integrate threejs with create react app from past 2 days.
All the 3d scene related files are in plain javascript and are stored in public/js folder.It throws an error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.

And when I add `objloader.js` in the local system it throws an error:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected line: `<!DOCTYPE html>` cannot be parsed by
>   OBJloader

But I am able to render the 3D scene without react.Thanks in advance.Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple GitHub repo to mess with three js stuff in a react environment. It uses the OBJ loader and the MTL loader in threes examples directory. Take a look and let me know if you have any questions: https://github.com/garretthogan/react-obj-viewer

edit: also, if you aren't serving up the static asset files like *.obj to your client side app then when you try to load them with the client side URL (localhost:3000/assets/models/myobj.obj) for example, the create react app server probably just returns the root index.html as a fail safe, which then throws the unexpected line error because your OBJ parser can't parse it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.I tried your github rep  ( https://github.com/garretthogan/react-obj-viewer). My 3d scene is rendering .But when i follow the same folder structure and add all the files given in your repo in the create react app it throws an error ` 'THREE' is not defined  no-undef`.Please help me out.Thank you.

Comment: Update:I have added my 3D scene in the create-react-app which throws an error `THREE is not defined no-undef`.Please have a look https://github.com/priyakrishnadev/webglapp.git

Comment: Three.js is not included anywhere. I was playing with this the other day and got create react app working with the three.js npm package.

Comment: @2pha I have included the three.js cdn "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.js" in the index.html .can i know where the error was ? can you please share that gitbhub repo if you have ?

Comment: I just did it as outlined at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248952/es6-import-of-three-js

Comment: I tried using the `import * as THREE from 'three'` but could not make it up https://github.com/priyakrishnadev/webglapp/blob/master/src/WebVR.js.

Comment: You have to add the three node module first `npm install --save three`

Comment: @2pha first thing i did was adding this node module as you suggested, kindly have a look at this https://github.com/priyakrishnadev/webglapp and do let me know what changes you did before it worked for you . If it is possible please share your repo. thanks